# I can't seem to get the first Twitter4J code example (Simple post on Twitter) to work. UpdateStatus(string) is undefined

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

So this is my problem right now:

I went to http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html as I just started to use twitter4j (version 4.0.2 as far as I can remember) and I wanted to try to code examples to get a basic understanding of T4J.
However, it seems like I can't even get the first example to work. This is my code right now:

```
import twitter4j.Status;
```

import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;

```
public class Twitter {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String latestStatus="Test";

    Twitter twitter = (Twitter) TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    Status status = twitter.updateStatus(latestStatus);
    System.out.println("Successfully updated the status to [" + status.getText() + "].");
}

}
```

This is exactly to code I found on code examples (Plus the string which should end up being the status). However, I always get an error at Status status=twitter.updateStatus(latestStatus), which is basically this:

```
The method updateStatus(String) is undefined for the type Twitter
```

I have literally no idea what could be wrong here. I mean in the end it's the official code example. Even the official doc is using strings as parameter for that method.

Can anyone give me a helping hand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add the JAR files to your build path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need couple of things to make this code work -
First you need to register your app with Twitter and generate OAuth Authentication. You will get following - consumerkey, consumersecret, accesstoken and accesstokensecret.

Using the keys and secret you would create a Twitter instance, which you can use to access your Twitter User ID.

Second you need to authorize your app to be able to write updates default permission is Read Only.

You can register and manage your app at https://apps.twitter.com/

Also about the twitter$j library version, please use a latest one.

Here is a code snippet to use the authentication keys and update the status -

```
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey("consumerKey")
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("consumerSecret")
        .setOAuthAccessToken("accessToken")
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("accessTokenSecret");

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

Status status = twitter.updateStatus("test");
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hello mbaxi!

Thanks for the help so far. I already registered my app, and I did the authentification via properties file before. I tried your way now, and I still get the "Type mismatch: cannot convert from twitter4j.Twitter to Twitter"-Error, this time in the new TwitterFactory line. 

So far I tried it with the latest stable version 4.0.2 and with the latest snapshot 4.0.3. I am getting the error in both versions.

Comment: @StefanSchranz - Are you sure you have included correct packages to resolve Twitter object ? version should not be an issue here. I have updated code above to include the imports.

Comment: @StefanSchranz - you can also try this Status status = new TwitterFactory(twitterConfigBuilder.build()).getInstance().updateStatus("test");

Comment: I get an conflict at the import "import twitter4j.Twitter;" which says "The import twitter4j.Twitter conflicts with a type defined in the same file".    I'm not sure if I imported it correctly, all I did was go to my project properties, java build path and then added the twitter4j-core jar as external jar in libraries.

Comment: okay try changing to twitter instance definition like below, note I used a fully qualified name for Twitter class - twitter4j.Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

Comment: It works now! But I face another problem: Exception in thread "main" 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
{"request":"\/1.1\/statuses\/update.json","error":"Read-only application cannot POST."}

However, in my application managemt I have my application listed with the highest permissions, which would be Read, Write and answer messages. The credentials must be right, as I just copied them out of my application Page. I don't know

Comment: about the system clock thing.          Thanks so far though, that was really helpful!

Comment: you need to authorize your app to be able to write updates default permission is Read Only, Check the Permissions tab in the Manage Apps section on https://apps.twitter.com/

Comment: Would be good if you could include the exception handling in the code, or mention it, since it's required. Also, this doesn't work on Android, because its not asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your class is called Twitter, so

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
```

will be interpreted as you trying to create an instance of your class `Twitter`, rather than an instance of `twitter4j.Twitter`. You could change the name of your class to something else, or change the library `Twitter` instances to `twitter4j.Twitter` instances to specify the difference.